# I did a ferroelectric hysteresis on some samples, but I can't explain these graphs, could someone help me please?

Tags: electric-fields

I first made 3 cycles for each sample, in fields from 0.5 to 3.5 (varying from 0.5 to 0.5) and with frequencies 10, 20, 50, 70, 100 and 200Hz. To get the measurements, I made a code in python using the GPT chat (which I checked the code before using) that centralizes the graphs and another that takes the values of each variable in the second cycle of the graph values. So I say graphics for fixed frequency 100Hz and fixed field 1.5, but some graphics look weird.

Saturated polarization is the maximum y
Remanent bias is y when x=0
And the coercive electric field is x when y=0

This is the link to the graphics:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JHipTIG43FyohUm4SCC45kWG9LXpsGhu/view?usp=sharing